# HSQL (in-memory) dramatically slows down when database grows

Tags: database, relational-database, hsqldb

iam doing some sort of transactions based on tpc-c test with hsqldb 
in-memory mode (no indices, default settings). When i start benchmark transaction speed is about 30000 TPCC transactions/minute but after few minutes the speed was slowed about 4-10x original rate here are rough results:

1:00 - 28000
  2:00 - 58000 
3:00 - 88000
4:00 - 115000
5:00  - 145000
6:00 - 154000
7:00 - 163000
8:00 - 168000
9:00 - 173000
10:00 - 176000

I think this has something to do with lack of memory but i dont know much about databases and memory management. When in-memory mode only i would expect the same speed all the time and then possibly out of memory error which will also happen after approx 270k transaction. Iam running this  on 4GB RAM computer, 64bit OS Linux (Lubuntu).

So my question is if its possible that this is normal behaviour and what should i do when i want to run this test (with in-memory mode) for about two hours to get more accurate results?

Comment: What to say except... Java.

Comment: The memory is getting full after 6 minutes and a lot of garbage collection is performed by Java, reducing the speed. You cannot run this test for 2 hours on your machine as the memory gets full in a short time.

Comment: Ok thx. I will change the program to wipe all data and start again with different seed for random data generator after  5 minutes so i should be able to meassure longer interval.